# Paste copied shape from current page till end of page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to insert a lot of images in msword with the image stretching to fit the page (minus the footer)
To do this I need to insert multiple shapes.

I just need it to paste the copied shape at the current page with the cursor and position the shape with horizontal alignment (left relative to page), vertical alignment (top relative to page), move to next page and redo the above till the last page

```
Sub PasteAndAlignItems()
    Dim totalPages As Integer
    Dim currentPage As Integer
    Dim startPosition As Range
    totalPages = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)
    Set startPosition = Selection.Range

    For currentPage = 1 To totalPages
        startPosition.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1
    Next currentPage
End Sub
```

I tried the above but it pastes the shapes repeatedly in the same page x times (x here is the amount of pages left)

**Edit:**
I realized that I can just copy the shapes with the paragraph/anchor and that will copy the position too so I don't need to repostion the pasted shape any more.

Apparently I kept returning to the same position due to startPosition so removing seems to solve that issue:

```
Sub PasteAndAlignItems()
    Dim totalPages As Integer
    Dim currentPage As Integer
    Dim startPosition As Range
    totalPages = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)

    For currentPage = 1 To totalPages
        Selection.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1
    Next currentPage
End Sub
```

I've seen vbas for inserting images in folders sequentially directly into document but none to fill shapes.
Can I do this? If so how?

Comment: Is there any content in word doc?

Comment: @taller Yes, I wanted it to start from current cursor position and move downwards toward towards the end of page

Comment: Do you mean the insert page only fill up the current page? The code don't need to handle other pages.

Comment: @taller I mean it should start from the page that contains the cursor then continue pasting on pages after that, ideally if i could also loop through a folder and for each image and fill up one shape consecutively that would be grand

Comment: The image might be distorted if the size of blank space on the page is different with the image.  Is there any conents on the next pages (till the end)? If so, where to insert the image?

Comment: The empty pages where created with Ctrl + enter. I've updated the question with a method that works. Is there a method to fill those shapes with images in a folder consecutively?

Comment: Do you mean insert a image which is a local file on your pc? Is there any restriction on image format (png, jpg, gif etc)?

Comment: They are local files (jpg) and should remain jpg when the shapes are filled

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PasteAndAlignItems()
    Dim totalPages As Integer
    Dim currentPage As Integer
    Dim startPosition As Range
    Dim inShp As InlineShape
    Dim pageWidth As Single, pageHeight As Single
    Dim pageLeftM As Single, pageRightM As Single
    Dim pageTopM As Single, pageBottomM As Single
    ' Get page parameters
    With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
        pageLeftM = .LeftMargin
        pageRightM = .RightMargin
        pageWidth = .pageWidth
        pageHeight = .pageHeight
        pageTopM = .TopMargin
        pageBottomM = .BottomMargin
    End With
    totalPages = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)
    ' Move to the beginning of the doc
    Selection.HomeKey Word.wdStory
    ' Loop through page
    For currentPage = 1 To totalPages
        ' Insert image from clipboard
        Selection.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine
        With ThisDocument.InlineShapes
            If .Count > 0 Then
                Set inShp = .Item(.Count)
                ' Resize image
                With inShp
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                    .Width = pageWidth - pageLeftM - pageRightM
                    .Height = pageHeight - pageTopM - pageBottomM
                End With
            End If
        End With
        ' Move to the next page
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1
    Next currentPage
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Selection.HomeKey method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.homekey?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158663160)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Document.PageSetup property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.pagesetup?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158008397)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]

---

*Update:*

> Question: loop through a folder and for each image and fill up one shape consecutively

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PasteAndAlignItems()
    Dim totalPages As Integer
    Dim currentPage As Integer
    Dim startPosition As Range
    Dim arrImage
    Const IMG_FOLDER = "D:\Temp\Img" ' modify as needed
    arrImage = GetImages(IMG_FOLDER)
    If Not IsArray(arrImage) Then
        MsgBox "No image file in " & IMG_FOLDER
        Exit Sub
    End If
    totalPages = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)
    For currentPage = 1 To totalPages
        ' Insert image
        ThisDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=arrImage(currentPage), _
            LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1
        If currentPage = UBound(arrImage) Then Exit For
    Next currentPage
End Sub
' Get image list in FolderPath
Function GetImages(ByVal FolderPath As String)
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim arrImage(), i As Long
    Const IMAGE_TYPE = "*.jpg" ' modify as needed
    'Dim FolderPath: FolderPath = "D:\Temp\" ' for testing
    Const MAX_IMAGE = 100
    ReDim arrImage(1 To MAX_IMAGE)
    If Not Right(FolderPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
    End If
    i = 0
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & IMAGE_TYPE)
    Do While FileName <> vbNullString
        i = i + 1
        arrImage(i) = FolderPath & FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    If i = 0 Then
        GetImages = ""
    Else
        ReDim Preserve arrImage(1 To i)
        GetImages = arrImage
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but this posts on all pages, which I don't want. Sorry for not including this information earlier.

Comment: I've updated the code.

Comment: The updated code fails to run ThisDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=arrImage(currentPage), _
            LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True gets highlighted in the editor.

Comment: What's the error number and error text? btw, they are two code lines.

Comment: Word just crashes now no errors they were automatically separated in the editor

Comment: Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005) Method 'AddPicture' of object 'InlineShapes' failed

Comment: Please restart Word application and create new document, then test the code.